# In many games, right clicking makes the camera spin around 180º

Tags: windows-7, usb, mouse

I been having for quite a long time a weird problem with games like Team Fortress 2, Portal and other Source Engine games where right clicking would spin the camera around and face almost to the opposite way I was originally looking, and to the floor.

To name a few other games, I've also had this problem with Serious Sam 3 (SS2 and SS1:HD were fine), Metro 2033 and some others, and I've always been able to fix the issue by disabling the mouse direct or raw input from the settings or via console commands.

But not with Alan Wake, that's why I'm asking for help!

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate x64, an nVidia GTX 650 TI, and my mouse is a [Logitech G5](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/359?osid=14&bit=64).

I have installed Logitech SetPoint to try if it fixed anything, but it did nothing. I also have Logitech Gaming Software to control my Keyboard and headset. (Yup, I like Logitech a lot).

The problem, as far as I know, is not related to the mouse itself, as I'm having the same issues with other mouses, to name them, a [Logitech M100](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/mouse-m100?crid=7) and [a cheap netbook mouse like those](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Mini-Retractable-USB-Optical-Scroll-Mouse-for-Laptop-PC-/190841069774?pt=Mice&hash=item2c6f03a0ce).

Of course, my antivirus (Microsoft Security Essentials) says that I have no virus, Malwarebites and the usual antivirus apps says that too, so I'm assuming that malware is not the issue, but here is the list of running processes, maybe you find something suspicious.

```
Image name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
System Idle Process              0 Services                   0        24 KB
System                           4 Services                   0     1.056 KB
smss.exe                       292 Services                   0       984 KB
csrss.exe                      456 Services                   0     4.072 KB
wininit.exe                    516 Services                   0     3.860 KB
csrss.exe                      544 Console                    1    11.544 KB
services.exe                   580 Services                   0    10.416 KB
lsass.exe                      604 Services                   0     9.172 KB
lsm.exe                        616 Services                   0     4.008 KB
winlogon.exe                   624 Console                    1     6.048 KB
svchost.exe                    756 Services                   0     9.572 KB
nvvsvc.exe                     816 Services                   0     5.832 KB
svchost.exe                    856 Services                   0     7.328 KB
MsMpEng.exe                    912 Services                   0    59.288 KB
svchost.exe                    312 Services                   0    18.416 KB
svchost.exe                    356 Services                   0   124.840 KB
svchost.exe                    344 Services                   0    16.880 KB
svchost.exe                    704 Services                   0    36.968 KB
audiodg.exe                   1028 Services                   0    27.840 KB
svchost.exe                   1144 Services                   0     6.116 KB
svchost.exe                   1272 Services                   0    22.428 KB
nvxdsync.exe                  1356 Console                    1    12.924 KB
nvvsvc.exe                    1364 Console                    1     9.228 KB
spoolsv.exe                   1548 Services                   0    10.308 KB
svchost.exe                   1592 Services                   0    14.100 KB
taskhost.exe                  1840 Console                    1    14.788 KB
dwm.exe                       1940 Console                    1    62.244 KB
StarWindServiceAE.exe         1948 Services                   0     4.844 KB
svchost.exe                   1968 Services                   0     4.816 KB
TeamViewer_Service.exe        2008 Services                   0    11.856 KB
explorer.exe                  1288 Console                    1    86.908 KB
OSPPSVC.EXE                   2536 Services                   0     8.588 KB
NisSrv.exe                    2572 Services                   0     5.292 KB
WmiPrvSE.exe                  2728 Services                   0    11.492 KB
svchost.exe                   2924 Services                   0     5.340 KB
RAVCpl64.exe                  3000 Console                    1     8.812 KB
XBoxStat.exe                  3016 Console                    1     7.328 KB
msseces.exe                   3024 Console                    1    11.852 KB
LCore.exe                     3040 Console                    1    50.016 KB
WUDFHost.exe                  2160 Services                   0     6.148 KB
vswitch64.exe                 2236 Console                    1    13.572 KB
robotaskbaricon.exe           2460 Console                    1    27.936 KB
dexpot.exe                     784 Console                    1    20.204 KB
SearchIndexer.exe             1764 Services                   0    22.848 KB
TeamViewer.exe                3136 Console                    1    17.516 KB
iTunesHelper.exe              3300 Console                    1     7.780 KB
Dexpot64.exe                  3340 Console                    1     3.132 KB
jusched.exe                   3376 Console                    1     4.504 KB
Dropbox.exe                   3404 Console                    1    74.692 KB
Steam.exe                     3512 Console                    1   126.028 KB
tv_w32.exe                    3700 Console                    1     4.756 KB
tv_x64.exe                    3708 Console                    1     3.888 KB
Dexcube.exe                   3820 Console                    1     3.932 KB
iPodService.exe               3852 Services                   0     6.560 KB
DexControl.exe                3904 Console                    1     5.208 KB
iSyncr.exe                    3956 Console                    1    29.964 KB
svchost.exe                   4448 Services                   0     5.116 KB
Skype.exe                     5060 Console                    1   107.892 KB
SetPoint.exe                  6496 Console                    1    45.908 KB
LogiAppBroker.exe             1628 Console                    1     7.128 KB
KHALMNPR.exe                  6728 Console                    1    12.196 KB
chrome.exe                    5256 Console                    1   123.264 KB
chrome.exe                    5028 Console                    1    58.500 KB
chrome.exe                    2868 Console                    1    74.560 KB
chrome.exe                    5512 Console                    1    26.232 KB
chrome.exe                    6384 Console                    1    18.752 KB
chrome.exe                    6480 Console                    1    22.732 KB
chrome.exe                    5340 Console                    1    19.816 KB
chrome.exe                    6740 Console                    1    18.684 KB
chrome.exe                    4016 Console                    1   124.872 KB
chrome.exe                    5200 Console                    1    22.196 KB
chrome.exe                    6044 Console                    1    23.892 KB
chrome.exe                    3116 Console                    1    31.720 KB
chrome.exe                    2808 Console                    1     8.692 KB
taskhost.exe                  6840 Console                    1     5.348 KB
firefox.exe                   3088 Console                    1   577.696 KB
iTunes.exe                    5844 Console                    1   142.380 KB
plugin-container.exe          2356 Console                    1    15.108 KB
FlashPlayerPlugin_11_7_70     5412 Console                    1    11.528 KB
FlashPlayerPlugin_11_7_70     5464 Console                    1    23.616 KB
taskmgr.exe                   4572 Console                    1    11.164 KB
PaintDotNet.exe               5828 Console                    1    65.576 KB
cmd.exe                       5416 Console                    1     3.068 KB
conhost.exe                   2424 Console                    1     5.764 KB
tasklist.exe                  6224 Console                    1     5.512 KB
```

Edit: Video is up!
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IkFo1tgjZgY

Thanks for any possible help!

Comment: I don't think it'll fix anything, but try updating your Logitech software - I recently discovered that they consolidated much of their software; The latest version of SetPoint manages my mouse, keyboard, and headset all from a single control panel. It's a nice update even if it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Everything is up to date, I triple checked that, hehe.

Comment: Sounds like cookie crumbs on your mouse pad to me ;)

Comment: Video is up! http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IkFo1tgjZgY
There you can see my issue better

Comment: Oh man, I thought you meant the video was rotated on your *screen* and not your character in-game.  There's definitely something funky going on sending mouse commands... I see you have `Dexcube`, do you get the same issue without it?  Can you try closing all running things that get started from `msconfig` and see if it persists?  (don't disable it in `msconfig`, just kill the tasks that it starts manually just in-case you disable something essential).

Comment: I didn't see anyone else on the internet with this problem and trying to explain my issue the best I could was proving difficult, so yeah, that's why I decided to record a video.
Well, I'm going to reboot and try what you said!

Comment: Oh, holy crap, it one of the processes! I've closed them all and the game is perfectly fine now! Now begins the fun game of hunting the bad process, yay!

Comment: Aw right! Turns out that VistaSwitcher was causing all the trouble.
Thank you very much for helping me out!
Post that comments as an answer so I can give you proper rep. :D

Comment: @Deses. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the process that was causing me all the trouble was VistaSwitcher, after killing the running process, my issue disappears.

I already contacted the developer to let him know what happened, I hope it gets fixed soon.

Comment: i've had a similar problem with tombraider and shadow warrior and the culprit was xmouse